# how to set edittext input type as a specific language other then default keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

If I have set android keyboard as default as english in keyboard setting and also enable the arabic keyboard. I clicked in EditText in my application then I am getting keyboard in english. But in my application there is an edittext to enter arabic. I need to show arabic keyboard. How to achieve this?  How to set default keyboard type for any particular EditText.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:inputMethod="Here You specify fully-qualified class name of your Inputmethod">
```

`BUT` about `android:inputMethod` attribute of `EditText` the Documentation says

```
If set, specifies that this TextView should use the specified input 
method (specified by fully-qualified class name). * Deprecated:  Use inputType instead. [string]
```

hope this will help you...

Comment: i knew that where to specify but my question is how to specify for a language keyboard ????